# Direct Query - Limitations in Latest Release

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have been asked to use Direct Query to bring in 3 data sources from 3 databases. In the power Bi desktop it allows me to do this but thought there was a restriction only allowing 1 distinct data source.

The power query editor however is giving me some not supported in direct query comments, when doing a merge transformation in power query,  so worried if this is actually going to work on deployment . What is the recommended way of conducting this ?

Is it transform the data and bring it in as 1 source with limited transforms in power query and in DAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you need to use Direct Query instead of Import mode? From my experience, when using DQ, it is always better to perform all transformations on source side, since many "regular" DAX features and transformations are disabled in DQ mode. One real example: for analyzing some live chat figures, I created one big fact table (SQL Server as a source) which contains all measures and transformations done in SQL. Then, I'm just direct querying this one single fact table, which improves performance significantly.

In case you need to be aware of all limitations of DQ, please refer to a following link: [Direct Query Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery#limitations-of-directquery)

Comment: Its a small once off piece of work with a very small data set, so looking to bypass a bigger power bi exercise. Its proving surprisingly challenging due to all of the limitations in the Dax and power query side.